# pusher , push actions to trigger soundmanager .play();

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pusher

i am trying to make a real time music player with pusher+php+jquery+ajax.

When a user clicks on #play button , it will send an ajax post to a php script , the php script will push the data to the specific channel and send a json encoded data back to the user.
A jquery will parse out the ajax data sent back by the php script.
If it's raction is "true" , then it plays the song, if "false" it stops the song.

But i kept on getting data undefined for the `actionCall` function
P/S I have included myjquery script , pusher script , soundmanager2 script to my html page.

My script as follows:

jQuery:

```
function ajaxCall(ajax_url, ajax_data, successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: ajax_data,
        time: 10,
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg.success) {
                successCallback(msg);
            } else {
                alert(msg.errormsg);
            }
        },
        error: function(msg) {}
    });
}


function actionCall(data) {
    if (data.raction == 'true') {
        MP3.play();
    }
    else {
        MP3.stop();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    pusher = new Pusher('i have added my app key');
    Pusher.channel_auth_endpoint = 'pusher_auth.php';
    nettuts_channel = pusher.subscribe('presence-music');

    pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
        nettuts_channel.bind('new_action', function(data) {
            actionCall(data);
        });
    });


    soundManager.url = 'swf';
    soundManager.flashVersion = 8;
    var MP3;
    var currentSong = 0;
    soundManager.onready(function() {

        MP3 = soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'sound' + currentSong,
            url: "mp3/song.mp3"
        });

    });


    $('#play').click(function() {
        ajaxCall('player.php', {
            'action': 'true'
        }, function(msg) {
            player.php
            actionCall(msg.data);
        });
    });

    $("#stop").click(function() {
        ajaxCall('player.php', {
            'action': 'false'
        }, function(msg) {
            player.php
            actionCall(msg.data);
        });
    });


});​
```

PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once 'Pusher.php';

$pusher = new Pusher(
    'i have added my app key', //APP KEY
    'i have added my app secret', //APP SECRET
    'added my app id' //APP ID
);

$action = $_POST['action'];

$pusher->trigger(
    'presence-music', //the channel
    'new_action', //the event
    array('raction' => $action) //the data to send
);


echo json_encode(array(
    'raction' => $action,
    'success' => true
));
exit();
?>
```

The PHP script works , returning :

```
{"raction":"true","success":true}
```

The problem is this error(in the jquery):

```
data is undefined
if(data.raction == 'true'){
```

Comment: For starters you should probably add all your js inside a immediatly self executing function so you don't pollute the global scope with functions. `(function ($){ /* your js goes here */ }(jQuery));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an undefined variable to your `actionCall`.

The `msg` variable passed to the success callback of your ajax request is what the server has sent you. This is clearly [documented here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#callback-functions). Because the `dataType` is set to 'json' jQuery will have parsed the result for you and passed the object to the callback function.

So for all intends and purposes, if an ajax request is successfull its success callback looks like this:

```
function(msg = {"raction":"true","success":true}) {
    if (msg.success) {
        successCallback(msg);
    } else {
        alert(msg.errormsg);
    }
}
```

(not actually working javascript, just for explanation purposes)

Then you pass the `msg` variable to the callback defined in the click event which would look like this:

```
function(msg = {"raction":"true","success":true}) {
   player.php /* This looks weird btw, I don't know what this is supposed to do but I'll ignore it since this doesn't look to be the problem. */
   actionCall(msg.data);
}
```

(not actually working javascript, just for explanation purposes)

Then you call the `actionCall` function  trying to pass `msg.data` but as you can probably deduce by now `data` isn't actually defined in the `msg` object.

Try passing `msg` as a whole instead, it should work.

So the callback defined for the ajax call would look something like this:

```
function(msg) {
    player.php
    actionCall(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do

```
actionCall(msg);
```

instead of

```
actionCall(msg.data);
```

since it is the msg object that contain your result